# Proof of an approximation of Welch

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, inverse-gamma-distribution

Let $S^2 = X/\nu$ where $X \sim \chi^2(\nu)$ and define $W = \frac{1}{S^2}$. In Welch's paper, "On the comparison of several mean values: an alternative approach" (1951), he gives the approximation in equation 9 on page 332*:

$$E(\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(W-1)^k}{k!}\partial^k) \approx 1 + \frac{2}{\nu}\partial + \frac{1}{\nu}\partial^2$$

where $\partial^k$ is a formal symbol representing the operation taking the $k$-th derivative.

How does he obtain this approximation?

**Comment 1:** It doesn't appear to me to be able to be done directly as $$E(\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(W-1)^k}{k!}\partial^k) = 1 + E(W-1)\partial + \frac{1}{2}E((W-1)^2)\partial^2 + ... $$ since $E(W-1)$ and $E((W-1)^2)$ only involve powers of $\frac{1}{v-2}$ and $\frac{1}{v-4}$.

**Comment 2:** The more well-known estimation from Welch's earlier paper, "A generalization of Student's problem",
$$E(\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{(S^2-1)}{k!}\partial^k) \approx 1 + \frac{1}{\nu}\partial^2 + \frac{4}{3\nu^2}\partial^3 + \frac{1}{2\nu^2}\partial^4$$ is obtained by formally expressing $$E(\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{(S^2-1)}{k!}\partial^k) = E(e^{(S^2-1)\partial})$$
and then arguing by expressing $$E(e^{(S^2-1)\partial}) = e^{-\partial}e^{K(\frac{\partial}{\nu})}$$ where $K$ is the cumulant generating function of $X$. He then obtains his estimate by Taylor-expanding $\log$ in $K(t) = \log(E(e^{tX}))$ about $1$ and then Taylor-expanding $e$ about $0$. I've tried to follow this procedure for $W$ but the (formal) moment generating function for $W$

1. is complex-valued which causes branch ambiguity in "formally" taking log
2. involves modified Bessel functions of the second kind

I think it is possible to proceed down this route with quite a bit of work, but given that Welch states this without proof, is there a simple argument to be made?

*Here $1=k=\lambda_t=\sigma_t^2$ and $\nu = f$ in the paper's notation